# Is it possible with pure CSS to position sticky multiple items in a grid stacked correctly?

Tags: css

I have two items in the same css grid column and I'd like them to act as if they were position sticky in one parent container, but I can't add a container to the HTML as at small widths the grid layout changes and these two items end up in separate parts of the grid.

As a minimal demo, this is what it should look like at large screen sizes:

```css
main {
  min-height: 300vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

.c1 {
  background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.c2 {
  align-self: start;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.c2 div {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="c1">
  </div>
  <div class="c2">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

And this is what it should do at narrow screen sizes:

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.c1 {
    background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
    min-height: 50vh;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.c2 {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.c3 {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="c1">
  </div>
  <div class="c2">Hello</div>
  <div class="c3">World</div>
</main>
```

As you can see, if I wrap the two elements in a common parent to sticky in the large screen case, there's no way (I know of) to separate them into different rows for the small screen case.

Are there any CSS-only ways to make this behavior work, or am I forced to resort to modifying the DOM in JavaScript?

The height of the two elements are not fixed, so trying to use a fixed `top: <some>px;` on the second of the two elements and `top: 0;` on the first doesn't work. More importantly, even if they did, when the parent grid scrolls out of view, they end up overlapping.

Comment: use CSS media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done with pure CSS.

Use the HTML structure you have for the narrower viewports.

You can then use `display: contents`to get the two elements within c2 to be included as grid items.

```html
<style>
  main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  }
  
  .c1 {
    background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
    min-height: 50vh;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  .c2 {
    display: contents;
  }
  
  .c2 *:first-child {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  .c2 *:last-child {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  @media (min-width:600px) {
    main {
      min-height: 300vh;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      margin-bottom: 100vh;
    }
    .c1 {
      background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 1;
      min-height: 0;
    }
    .c2 {
      align-self: start;
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 1;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      display: initial;
    }
    .c2 div {
      padding: 30px 0;
    }
  }
</style>
<main>
  <div class="c1">
  </div>
  <div class="c2">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
  </div>
</main>
```